# Laravel: Trying to get a property of non-object

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

Im trying to get a certain column in my view, but im having an error saying

"Trying to get a property of non-object"

Can you help me guys?

**Here's my Controller**

```
    $subject = Subject1::where('teacher_id', '=' , Auth::user()->id)->lists('section_name');

    return View::make('teacher.view_sectionassigned')
        ->with('subject', $subject);
```

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following one

```
$subject = Subject1::where('teacher_id', '=' , Auth::user()->id)->get(array('section_name'));

return View::make('teacher.view_sectionassigned')
    ->with('subject', $subject);
```